# Неправильная работа cos()

Tags: c++

Проблема в том, что если взять угол в 90 градусов, перевести его в радианы и найти его косинус, результат не соответствует действительности. Что-то вроде -4.5264861e-008

Comment: Правильно. В действительности всё совсем не так, как на самом деле. (А если непонятно, то можно вспомнить о том, что вычисления с плавающей точкой суть вычисления приближённые и ошибки округления вполне могут иметь место)

Comment: Какой компилятор? У меня gcc дает точно 0

Comment: Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Разобрался. Вы, наверное, используете переменную типа `float`. С ней у меня тоже выходит -4.3711e-8. А вот `double` все ОК.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Во-первых, косинус (как и все тригонометрические функции) вычисляется по разложению в ряд Тейлора. В идеале ряд нужно продолжать до бесконечности, в реальности же он вычисляется до тех пор, пока не будет достигнута заданная точность. Причём эта точность может быть меньше, чем точность представления числа в `float`'е.

Во-вторых, `float` не резиновый, в нём всего 23 двоичных разряда отведены на мантиссу. Соответственно, на каждом шаге точность будет падать.

В-третьих, не стоит забывать, что благодаря Интелу 2.0f * 2.0f = 3.99999999999f (работает только на семействе процессоров x86).

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, в результате заменил банальным костылем.

Comment: Дайте угадаю, вместо того чтобы сравнивать числа напрямую вы берёте модуль их разности и сравниваете его с какой-нибудь маленькой константой? Это не костыль. Точнее, костыль, но настолько распространённая практика, что костылём её считать как-то не принято.

Comment: нет, не угадали, да, я просто сравниваю числа. =D

Comment: @fori1ton: Подождите, вы уверены? Формат float позволяет точное представление целых чисел до 0xffffff.

Comment: Что значит работает только на х86? Они не совместимы IEEE 754 по вашему?

Comment: @IronVbif, они-то совместимы, но в ранних моделях есть оригинальный косяк в аппаратной реализации FPU, благодаря чему возможны подобные казусы. К сожалению, чёткого пруфлинка на именно этот баг мне найти не удалось (поиск по фразе `pentium arithmetic bug` ведут на статьи про [баг с FDIV][1]), но я совершенно чётко помню, как сам на это натыкался.

  [1]: http://www.cs.niu.edu/other/pentium.html

Comment: @fori1ton, Дак говори - баг был, когда-то в бородатые года, о котором я не помню, не знаю где точно он был и был ли вообще, а так же  куда/когда в конечном итоге он пропал.

Comment: @fori1ton все верно, кроме одного - там не ряд Тейлора :)